# Scala how to get LocalDate by pattern

Tags: scala, localdate

I try to get `LocaDate` by format so i took this function that receive date and search for format to parse:

```
def getLocalDate(date: String): LocalDate = {

    val pattern1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM, yyyy")
    val pattern2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy")
    val pattern3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd")
    val pattern4 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/YYYY")
    val pattern5 = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE

    val result = Try {
      LocalDate.parse(date, pattern1)
    } recover {
      case _ => LocalDate.parse(date, pattern2)
    } recover {
      case _ => LocalDate.parse(date, pattern3)
    } recover {
      case _ => LocalDate.parse(date, pattern4)
    } recover {
      case _ => LocalDate.parse(date, pattern5)
    }

    result.get
  }
```

Usage:

```
var s1 = "01/08/2010"
getLocalDate(s1)
```

But got an error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01/08/2010' could not be parsed at index 0
```

And i don;t know why and what goes wrong.

Comment: I don't know scala but it seems you have to wrap each LocalDate.parse-call in a try block.

Comment: I assume your example date "01/08/2010" should be matched by pattern 4, but it uses uppercase `YYYY` instead of `yyyy`.

Comment: Same error with YYYY or yyyy

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested it using the `yyyy` pattern and it worked. If I use the `YYYY` pattern it throws.

Comment: pattern4 should be `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

import scala.util.Try

def getLocalDate(date: String): java.time.LocalDate = {
  val pattern1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM, yyyy")
  val pattern2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy")
  val pattern3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd")
  val pattern4 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
  val pattern5 = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE

  val result = Try {
    LocalDate.parse(date, pattern1)
  } recover {
    case _ => LocalDate.parse(date, pattern2)
  } recover {
    case _ => LocalDate.parse(date, pattern3)
  } recover {
    case _ => LocalDate.parse(date, pattern4)
  } recover {
    case _ => LocalDate.parse(date, pattern5)
  }

  result.get
}
var s1 = "01/08/2010"
getLocalDate(s1)
```

This works nicely in REPL (Scala 2.11.8, Java 1.8).

Your mistake was to include "YYYY" in last pattern instead of "yyyy".
Also, take a look at package nscala-time. Maybe it will provide better bindings for your applications.